# How can I set session in action composition in Play framework using Java

Tags: java, session, playframework

I have following code that should set a redirect url to `session`, but it doesn't do that.

```
public class WithUserActionAnnotation extends Action<WithUserAction> {

    public F.Promise<Result> call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
        User user = (User) ctx.args.get(SecureSocial.USER_KEY);

        if (user != null) {
            return delegate.call(ctx);
        } else {
            Result redirect = Results.redirect(routes.LoginPage.login());
            redirect.session().put(SecureSocial.ORIGINAL_URL, ctx.request().uri());
            return F.Promise.pure(redirect);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me

```
Http.Session session = Http.Context.current().session();
session.put(SecureSocial.ORIGINAL_URL, ctx.request().uri());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ctx._requestHeader().session().get("AUTH");
```

Comment: please add more description